# Android: Problem when calling a variable from AbstractActivity class which is extended on activities

Tags: android

I have many acitivities extending to one AbstractActivity. i.e:

```
    class ActivityA extends AbstractActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract)
        }
Button1.setOnClickListener {
x = 5
}
}
```

and

```
open class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity() { ... 
    var x : Int? = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract)
            Toast.makeText(this, "varInAbstract=" + varInAbstract, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

There is a variable declared in Abstract Activity. I.e: `var varInAbstract`. When I change the value of this variable in another activity, it changes in the activity. But when I call this varInAbstract in AbstractActivity class, its value is not the last assigned value by activity class, but the previous from the last one. **I think the changes made in Activity classes don't apply on AbstractActivity class.** The toast message always show value "0". Is there a solution? Or a workaround?

Any help?

[image]

Comment: How are you accessing that variable in `AbstactActivity` class?

Comment: And this function is present in `AbstractActivity`?

Comment: How are you invoking this method? You cannot directly create an object of `AbstractActivity`. Please post the codes of both the activities and highlight where you are accessing that variable from different classes.

Comment: What do you mean by invoking? Excuse me I am not a professional.. If you mean how I declared first, I declared this way:                    var varInAbstract: Int? = 1

Comment: I mean, where are you calling this function? Also, I really insist, you post the whole body of both the classes.

Comment: I added the picture to be clear if you still didn't understand. The problem is already clear enough I think

Comment: I still think you should post the code of both the activities. I don't know why you are not doing that. Using that, it would be possible for me to reproduce the problem on my machine, solve it and help you. Please check  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  It is possible that while you think that you have asked a well explained question, that is not the case.

Comment: I edited my question post due to your suggestion